# Rails: how do I use a template from somewhere other than the file system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, actionview

I have an application that needs to support a small set of trusted users uploading new templates. I'll store them in the database or in S3. My question is: how do I tell the controller to render a given template? Of course, I could do it with a manual ERB call:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    template_source = find_template(params[:name])
    template = Erubis::Eruby.new(template_source)
    render :text => template.result({ :some => @data })
  end
end
```

But then I lose things like helpers and the automatic copying of instance variables.

Comment: there is a great section abot template handling in `Crafting Rails applications`

Comment: it (the crafting rails app example on templates) really is nearly perfect for your needs

Comment: I'll be sure to read it. Thanks!

Comment: For those who don't have the book, that chapter implements an [ActionView::Resolver](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Resolver.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using render :inline

```
render :inline => find_template(params[:name])
```

Comment: I like the ActionView::Resolver suggestion that some made in comments, but as this is the only actual answer and it works, I'm accepting it.